# Optimize copyTable function to Oracle in Java

Tags: java, oracle, performance, dynamic-sql

I like to copy some tables into my Oracle database, so I wrote this Java method:

```
public static int copyTable (String cmdSelect, String cmdInsert, String sourceURL) throws SQLException {
    int rowCount = 0;

    try {
        Connection conOra = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
        Connection conGauss = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL, "username", "password");

        PreparedStatement sthSel = conGauss.prepareStatement(cmdSelect);
        PreparedStatement sthIns = conOra.prepareStatement(cmdInsert);

        ResultSet rs = sthSel.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            for( int c = 1; c <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); c++ ) {
                sthIns.setObject(c, rs.getObject(c), rsmd.getColumnType(c), rsmd.getScale(c));
            }
            sthIns.addBatch();
            rowCount++;
            if (rowCount % 10000 == 0) {
                sthIns.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        sthIns.executeBatch();
        
        rs.close();
        sthSel.close();
        sthIns.close();
        conGauss.close();
        conOra.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return rowCount;
}
```

I created function in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copyTable(cmdSelect VARCHAR2, cmdInsert VARCHAR2, sourceURL VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER 
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Gauss.copyTable(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return int';
```

and I call it like this:

```
DECLARE
    cmdSelect VARCHAR2(1000) := 'SELECT NRID, NEID, NRNAME, NR_NAME, NBTYPE, NETYPE, GNODEBID, INVALIDTIME, OBJECTSTATUS FROM D_NR';
    cmdInsert VARCHAR2(1000) := 'INSERT INTO D_NR_COPY (NRID, NEID, NRNAME, NR_NAME, NBTYPE, NETYPE, GNODEBID, INVALIDTIME, OBJECTSTATUS) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    ret INTEGER;
BEGIN
    ret := copyTable(cmdSelect, cmdInsert, 'some URL');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'ret = ' || ret );
    COMMIT;
END;
```

My first tests are working fine, the procedure works as expected. But I am a bit concerned about performance, some tables will be rather big. I have no clue about Java.

Do I have to loop `for ( int c = 1; c <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); c++ )`  for every row or is there any faster way of doing it?

Is it possible and beneficial to read the source tables in batches instead of row by row with `while ( rs.next() )`?

Note, a plain `INSERT INTO D_NR_COPY (...) SELECT ... FROM D_NR` does not work, because the source database is not an Oracle database.

Comment: Can't you create database links to source databases? Single insert-select sql using db links would be much faster

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov No, DB link to non-Oracle is not possible. You could use "Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC", however the source DB is a Huawei GaussDB and our Oracle runs on Redhat Linux. Because of the Trump/US ban, Huawei may not provide ODBC drivers for their DB on Redhat, same applies for Windows. A migration of our Oracle to another Linux (e.g. Suse Linux) is no option either.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC driver usually fetches multiple rows. The default number of rows depends on the driver (e.g. Oracles's JDBC driver has a default of 10). You can check the default fetch size through Statement.getFetchSize() and increase it through Statement.setFetchSize(int). Note that the fetch size is just a hint for the JDBC driver, it may ignore or override the size. If the set fetch size should be ignored i recommend to check the doc of your JDBC driver.

Although theoretically possible (its up to the JDBC driver implementation), it is very unlikely that calls to methods of ResultSetMetaData trigger additional calls to the DB. It is more likely that the whole metadata is already in memory. In this case there's no need to optimize something here.